# Rails 4: Use an html premade form as a rails form. HTML form to Rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to use a pre-made, generic HTML/CSS/Javascript form as a Rails form within my app. I've always used the rails form_for to create forms but I am trying  to use a suite/framework from CodeCanyon called [Munda Forms](http://codecanyon.net/item/munda-forms-clean-modern-responsive-web-forms/10114467?WT.oss_phrase=&WT.oss_rank=30&WT.z_author=rcwthemes&WT.ac=search_list).

I've included all of the frameworks it uses already and have the forms looking correctly in my app, but I haven't found an easy way to have it work nicely with my Controller & Model.

Is there an easy way to use this pre-made design within my app? Basically, I'm asking how I can use just straight HTML/CSS to pass the input form data into my Controller. I keep getting authenticity_token errors when I try to pass it in because I'm not using a Rails form_for helper.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the most simple example I can show you. Here's an example of the HTML that I am given. I am also given CSS & Javascript but I don't think that will be necessary to edit.

Below is the view (_client_form1.html.erb) that I'm editing.

```
<div class="form-container tabs-form animated fadeInDown">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="tabs-form" class="rcw-form container-fluid">
<header>
  <h3 class="form-main-heading">Page 1/4: Basic Info</h3>
</header>
<fieldset class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <legend><span>Select your charge.</span></legend>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div id="tabs-example-1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span class="icon-home22"></span>DUI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><span class="icon-globe"></span>DWAI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3"><span class="icon-newspaper3"></span>DUID</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tab-1">
        <p>TAB1 TAB1 TAB1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, omnis.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-2">
        <p>TAB2 TAB2 TAB2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-3">
        <p>TAB3 TAB3 TAB3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12"><span class="label">Number of Offenses</span>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div id="increments-slider"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="increments-amount" class="amount"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="zipcode" class="sr-only">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control ff-rounded">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<footer class="ff-rounded-b">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary ff-rounded">
</footer>
```

And here's my controller, (contacts_controller.rb) a very basic mailer. My contact.rb model

```
 class ContactsController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @contact = Contact.new
 end

 def create
   @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
   @contact.request = request

   if @contact.deliver
     flash[:success] = "Thanks for reaching out. We will get back to you back shortly!"
     redirect_to '/'
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

end
```

I've also added the fields that my model accepts if it helps.

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :offenseType
      t.string :offenseNumber
      t.string :bestDay
      t.string :rankImportance
      t.string :comments

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The error that I get with both my code and your suggestion is: "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in ContactsController#create"

Any other ideas?

My application.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> <%= full_title(yield(:title)) %> </title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= favicon_link_tag %>

  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"> </div>

    <%= yield %>

    <div class="container">
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
    match '/contact_us', to: 'contacts#new',       via: 'get'
    match '/contact_us', to: 'contacts#create',    via: 'post'
```

With the posted html code and script from Aswin Ramakrishnan, here's the output from the webBrick server.

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-12 23:26:58 -0700
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters:   {"authenticity_token"=>"uybxcY9FfrfoYo/UrvChbYPp3oB8aBv3YLu2u1e4/JE=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"test name", "email"=>"test email", "phone"=>"5555555555"}}
  Rendered contacts/_client_form5.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)

Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 33.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Rails forms are ultimately rendered as HTML forms. Can you post a form for example? Along with your controller code. We can tell you what you need to do.

Comment: What error are you getting now that you solved the token issue?

Comment: I've added what's happening with the given anser from Aswin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here is what you need to do -

Create an `application.html.erb`, if you haven't already. It should look something like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Application Title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>  
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Any Master Page content that you'd want -->
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no connection between your controller and the HTML you've posted. Even though, I won't be editing that HTML the way you want, I can show how an HTML form can submit to a rails controller. It would look something like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myFormAuthToken').val($('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val());
  $('#myFormAuthToken').attr('name', 'authenticity_token');
  
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('div').html($('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="j5m1CY+P0PEByd8/9U4y5xSqAMR4j2xE78F5NAZ0KDU="/>

<form id="new_contact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/contacts" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input id="myFormAuthToken" type="hidden" />Your Name:
  <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact[name]" placeholder="Contact's Name" />
  <br/>
  <br/>Your email:
  <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="contact[email]" placeholder="Contact's Email" />
  <br/>
  <br/>Your phone:
  <input type="text" id="contact_phone" name="contact[phone]" placeholder="Contact's Phone" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit the form</button>
</form>

<br/><br/>
<b>Serialized Data:</b><div></div>
```

I think you get the point, the name should be in the format of **object[attribute_name]** for the HTML form to submit to a Rails controller.

Comment: That still does not work. I've attached what my application.html looks like, and it is very similar to what yours looks like. I'm still getting the same error. When the Rails helper, form_for( ), is called, it automatically converts to html and that html that is output contains that authenticity token which is missing.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes. The form does use jquery. I additionally found the Rails helper:

 <%= form_authenticity_token %>

But this still fails, this time unable to successfully call the controller's "create" method and send the email. On the other hand, if I use a Rails form_for helper, it will send correctly.

Comment: Yes. You can use that too. Or you can use the authenticity_token value injected from the application.html.erb

Comment: Ok. I've updated the answer. You should be able to include the authenticity token via jQuery as I showed.

Comment: What that, I can get it to accept the authenticity token but it still will not call the controller method, "create", successfully. Thanks for all the help with this by the way!

Comment: What is your form's action and method?

Comment: The form's action and method, if called properly and functions correctly is:
 action="/contacts" 
 method="post"

Comment: Do you have resources: : contacts in your routes.rb?

Comment: Yes I do, like so:
    resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
        match '/contact_us', to: 'contacts#new',       via: 'get'
        match '/contact_us', to: 'contacts#create',    via: 'post'